# Entity Framework Console app connecting to the wrong database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an EF code first web app that is working fine and connects to the database server correctly.  I have added a console app to the solution to test out the logic for a service that will go along with the app.

Was having a head scratcher on why the console app wasn't saving the data so I pared it down to a simple fetch from the database and it turns out the original console app was saving the record, but to a different database than what is specified in the connection string.

Here is the connection string from the app.config:

```
  <add name="DatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xx.x.xx; Initial Catalog=OKWU_Gateway; User ID=xxxxx; Password=********; Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DevelopmentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\OKWU_Gateway.mdf" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The DatabaseContext is

The console app is very simple

```
    Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var query = from u in db.Users where u.Id == 1 select u;
            foreach (User u in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(u.Id + " " + u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

but instead of connecting to the db on the remote server it is connecting to sqlexpress on the dev machine and hitting this database.

```
UniversityGateway.Data.DatabaseContext
```

I tried changing the connection string to point the |DataDirectory| to the SQL connection string and that didn't make any difference.  The connection strings are the same as what is in the web.config and as I said, the web app works fine.

Any ideas on what I'm missing or point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Comment: just checking...you don't have any stray resource files hanging around do you?

Comment: why in the world would someone downvote this and not bother leaving a comment.

Comment: How does your context's constructor look like?

Comment: edited the question.  Not sure why this keeps getting downvoted without a comment.  What is wrong with my question that deserves a downvote?

Comment: digging deeper, it seems to be ignoring the connection string alltogether and falling through to .\sqlexpress.

Comment: Have you checked your app.config file being copied into your bin(compile output) directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a lot of digging I found a solution.  Not sure if it is the correct/best one but it works so I can move on.

Since the console app wasn't respecting the connection string in the app.config, I specified the connection in the code with

```
db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Still feel like I'm missing something here though.

Discovered that an additional part of my problem is that EF Codefirst doesn't play well with Sql Server 2005 DateTime data types.

Comment: There is a good chance the issue is related to the constructor of your DbContext class so please follow @Ladislav 's comment and paste it in your question.

Comment: actually it is because the ef datetime datatypes don't synch up with the sql 2005 datetime datatype.  Had we generated an emdx file from an existing database then we could add the providermanifest token setting to allow it to play nice with 2005, but using code first that wasn't an option.    Fixing that in the re-write.